# how to use awk to merge files with common fields and print in another file

Tags: bash, file, join, awk, merge

I have read all the related questions, but still quite confuse...

I have two files tab separated.
**file1** (breaks added for readability):

```
a 15 bac
g 10 bac
h11 bac
r 33 arq
t 12 euk
```

**file2** (breaks added for readability):

```
0 15 h 3 5 2 gf a a g e g s s g g 
p 33 g 4 5 2 hg 3 1 3 f 5 h 5 h 6 
g 4  r 8 j 9 jk 9 j 9 9 h t 9 k 0
```

Output desired (breaks added for readability):

```
bac 15 h 3 5 2 gf a a g e g s s g g 
arq 33 g 4 5 2 hg 3 1 3 f 5 h 5 h 6
ND g 4  r 8 j 9 jk 9 j 9 9 h t 9 k 0
```

Just that. I need to print the complete **file2** but in the first column I need to replace with the third column of **file1** only when `$2` of **file2** is the same that `$2` of **file1**...
**file1** is larger than **file2**, but still could happen that `$2` from **file2** is not present in **file1**, in that case print in the first column **ND**.
I'm sure it must be simple, but I have problems with `awk` managing two files. Please, if someone could help me...

Comment: How does second line becomes 33 when $2 of file2 is 10 and $2 of arq is 10?

Comment: Sorry. my mistake. File2 should have a 33 in the second line

Comment: So final output should skip first column of file2 or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this awk command:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$3;next} {$1=(a[$2])?a[$2]:"ND"} 1' file1 file2
bac 15 h 3 5 2 gf a a g e g s s g g
arq 33 g 4 5 2 hg 3 1 3 f 5 h 5 h 6
ND 4 r 8 j 9 jk 9 j 9 9 h t 9 k 0
```

**Explanation:**

- `FNR==NR` - Execute this block for first file in input i.e. `file1`
- `a[$2]=$3` - Populate an associative array `a` with key as `$2` and value as `$3` from file1
- `next` - Read next line until `EOF` on first file
- **Now operating in `file2`**
- `$1=(a[$2])?a[$2]:"ND"` - Overwrite `$1` with `a[$2]` if `$2` is found in array `a`, otherwise by literal string `"ND"`
- `1` - print the output

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works perfect, just another silly question please: What if the separator fields are blank spaces instead of tab?

Comment: By default awk treats any whitespace as field delimiter i.e. space or tab. So both space and tab are fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with join + awk command as below:

```
join -t ' ' -a2  -1 2 -2 2 test1.txt test2.txt | awk 'BEGIN { start = 5; end = 18 } { if (NF == 16) { temp = $1; $1 = "ND " $2; $2 = temp; print } else { printf("%s %s ", $3, $1); for (i=start; i<=end; i++) printf ("%s ", $i); printf("\n");}}'
```